# Linear Transformation Question - Vector spaces, span, dim

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \to W$ ($V,W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces).

If $H$ is a subspace of $V$, then $\dim T(H) \le \dim H$.

My attempt:

Let {$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$} be a basis for $H$.

Let $w \in T(H)$, so there exists a $v \in H$ such that $T(v)=w$.

Write $v=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$, so $w=T(v)=a_1T(v_1)+...+a_nT(v_n)$.

So $T(H)=$span{$T(v_1),...,T(v_n)$}.

But isn't that mean that $\dim T(H)=n$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: i think it may be better if you assume the contrary and look for a contradiction.

Comment: Your proof is correct and no, this means the dimension of $T(H)\le n$ because it may not require all of the $T(v_i)$ to get $T(v)$.

Comment: Just for your information, there is an  equation relating dim(T(H)), dim(H). It is the one and only rank-nullity dimension theorem. A simple yet fundamental theorem for linear algebra ;)

Comment: To expand a little on John Douma's comment, it may be that the $T(v_i)$ are not linearly independent. For example, the projection map $$P_1 : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2 : (x,y) \mapsto (x, 0)$$ $P_1(\Bbb R^2) = \Bbb R \times \{0\}$, which is one-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! You really helped me here!